# Slice json dataframe in python 2.6

Tags: python, json

I am trying to slice a df but somewhere I am doing something wrong.

I have a json file which comes from a query like this:

```
def query(same params):
      sql code:
return myquery.to_json()
```

Then I have a function `getData()` and here I am making same calculations and trying to slice the df

```
def getData():
...
 myquery = query(same params)
 slice = query['Names'].tolist()
```

But I get an error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to slice the json using their keys :

```
 try:
     decoded = json.loads(query_result)
     for item in decode['data']:
        do_your_stuff
 except (JSONDecodeError, KeyError):
      pass or handle
```